# Trim/excerpt content in expressionengine

Tags: php, content-management-system, expressionengine, trim

Just installed EE everything seems clear however I can't seem to find a solution to automatically trim body text to say 50 characters long, is there a built in function to do this or a plugin?

Done a fair bit of searching to no avail, there seemed to be a plugin called EETrim which is no longer supported which leads me to believe it was maybe shipped with the latest version of EE however I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TruncHTML is one of the best ones (as it automatically handles closing of html tags):
http://utilitees.de/ee.php/trunchtml

Example:

```
{exp:trunchtml chars="50" inline="..." ending="<a href='{path=site/comments}'>read on</a>"}
{body}
{/exp:trunchtml}
```

http://www.devot-ee.com is always your best friend when searching for EE add-ons :)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, have added devot-ee to my favourites, many thanks!